# How to center 4 elements 2 in lines?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have html like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sit</a></li>
  </li>
</nav>
```

is it possible to center ul that to look like this:

```
|          lorem ipsum          |
|           dolor sit           |
```

I'm working on responsive site and on small screen I need the text to be in two lines and center.

Comment: I think that it is possible. Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think using floating elements creates more problems for beginner developers than solutions. I would go for the following solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/W7aLA/

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sit</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

li:nth-of-type(even):after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

**OR**

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

li:first-child+li+li {
    clear: left; /* because nth-child doesn't work in IE8 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `float: left` and `clear: left`:

```
ul li {
   float: left;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n + 1) {
   clear: left;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2mpES/)